# How to unit test a static constructor using Rhino mocks

Tags: c#, testing, rhino-mocks

I am using Visual Studio 2012 and MSTest for unit testing. For generating mocks I am using free Rhino Mocks. But I am unable to write unit test cases for static constructor.
I am performing operations like initializing a WCF service using static constructor. Can someone suggest me how to write unit test for static constructor or some refactoring required for it?

Sample code:

```
static PublisherSubscriber()
{ 
    _isServiceInitializing = true;
    Initialize();
    _mefInitializer = MEFInitializer.GetInstance();
    _subscriptionManagerInstance = SubscriptionManager.GetInstance();
    requestManagerInstance = RequestManager.GetInstance();
}
```

In the above code subscription manager and requestmanager initializes the datastore on their initialization. The ultimate requirement is to mock such dependencies which is not possible to inject in static constructor OR a way to refactor the code to make it unit testable

Comment: What behaviour do you want to test? Could you please post a code sample?

Comment: sample code-
static PublisherSubscriber()
{
     _isServiceInitializing = true;
     Initialize();
     _mefInitializer = MEFInitializer.GetInstance();

     _subscriptionManagerInstance = SubscriptionManager.GetInstance();
    _requestManagerInstance = RequestManager.GetInstance();
        }

In the above code subscription manager and requestmanager initializes the datastore on their initialization. 
The ultimate requirement is to mock such dependencies which is not possible to inject in static constructor OR a way to refactor the code to make it unit testable.

Comment: I have submitted the edit for it but when you add code to an existing question. Edit your question and add the code.